# $\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}k\Bigr)^p\le\frac{p}{p-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}k\Bigr)^{p-1}a_k$ for nonnegative $(a_k)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am struggling with the following task:

> Let$$1<p<\infty , n\in \mathbb{N}, a_1\geqslant 0,\dots,a_n\geqslant 0.$$
>   Prove that
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}\Bigr)^p \le \frac{p}{p-1}\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}\Bigr)^{p-1}a_k\Biggr)$$
>   and
>   $$\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}\Bigr)^p\Biggr)^{1/p} \le \frac{p}{p-1} \Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p \Biggr)^{1/p}.$$

**My attempt:**
Let $f(z)=z^p$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}\Bigr)^p
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f\Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}\Bigr)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^{\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}} f'(t)dt\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(\int_0^{\frac{a_1}{k}} f'(t)dt+\dots+\int_{\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{k-1}}{k}}^{\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}{k}} f'(t)dt \Bigr)\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \Biggl(\frac{a_1}k f'\Bigl(\frac{a_1}k\Bigr)+\frac{a_2}kf'\Bigl(\frac{a_1+a_2}k\Bigr)+\dots+\frac{a_k}kf'\Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}k\Bigr)\Biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac pk\Biggl(a_1\Bigl(\frac{a_1}k\Bigr)^{p-1}+a_2\Bigl(\frac{a_1+a_2}k\Bigr)^{p-1}+\dots+a_k\Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}k\Bigr)^{p-1}\Biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac pk\Biggl(\sum_{j=1}^k a_j \Bigl(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_j}{k}\Bigr)^{p-1}\Biggr),
\end{align*}

but I'm not sure how to proceed. Could anyone help, please? Thanks

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible to prove the inequality following your steps, so if you will excuse me, I will just post my solution.

First inequality:

Let $S_k = (a_1 + \dots + a_k )/k$ for each valid $k$, and define $S_0 = 0$. We shall prove that 
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{k}{p-1}\right) S_k^p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} S_k^{p-1} a_k + \frac{k-1}{p-1} S_{k-1}^p
$$
for all $1\leq k\leq n$. If this is true, summing the inequalities for $k = 1,2,\dots,n$, you will get the desired result.

To prove the inequality above, substitute $a_k = kS_k - (k-1)S_{k-1}$, then it reduces to
$$
p S_k^{p-1} (S_{k-1}-S_k) \leq S_{k-1}^p - S_k^p
$$
This can be easily proved by dividing the cases by whether $S_k\geq S_{k-1}$ or not.

Second Inequality is [Hardy's Inequlity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!